# Revit Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to process time limit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We have an issue with a Revit model that doesn't work. The log file shows the following information:

```
*[05/09/2021 11:01:07] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 21.1.20.44 (VersionNumber) 2021 (SubVersionNumber) 2021.2
[05/09/2021 14:01:00] Error: Revit Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to process time limit.*
```

I have seen the customer open this file on their own machine and I noticed a plugin then wanted to connect to another service and also a dialog popped up. Is it possible to find out what the RCE is waiting for? Because the Revit model isn't big at all +/- 150 mb. Typically these sort of files don't take much more than a minute to be processed.

Does the RCE also produce a journal file? Is it possible to review it?

Comment: Hi @Daniel - I looked at the logs for `b27223519e824cdc90df80a1af6e718b` and did not find any thing obvious. Is there a way you can help us with a minimal reproducible sample? If the input file is not sensitive could you share it with `forge.help`[at]`autodesk.com` and refer both the stack overflow posts you made?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for providing the model. We had a look, the hanging seems not because of dialog popped up. 

Could you try removing all structural connections in the model by going to Structure tab > Structural Connection Settings > select all the Loaded Connections: on the right-side > Remove and send the copy of the model to the job? Please let us know the result